# Setting Java Runtime Environment for Glassfish Embedded Message Broker

Tags: java, glassfish, jms, openmq

I am trying to setup JMS in Glassfish 2.1.1 in my local windows machine by following the below links

http://www.packtpub.com/article/configuring-jms-resources-in-glassfish-1

http://www.packtpub.com/article/configuring-jms-resources-in-glassfish-2

After setting up the initial configurations, when i am trying to start the Embedded Open MQ Broker (command **imqbrokerd -tty**), i am getting the below error

```
    Message Queue 4.4 Broker: Invalid Java Runtime 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\jre\..': 2 The system cannot find the file specified.
```

though i have set my JAVA_HOME environment variable to jdk1.6, i am not able to figure out from where the broker is picking up the wrong runtime environment.

**EDIT** : In the glassfish\config\asenv.bat, the property **AS_JAVA** is also set to the right Jdk **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21**

How and which configuration  should i change to make the Broker point to the right Java Runtime Environment.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: What is the output of **java -version** and **which java**?

Comment: java -version gives the path to the right JAVA_HOME which is 1.6.0. What i am not clear about is where does GF pick up jdk1.5 for mq

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting similar errors but I did some changes like

Change the `Java_Home` variable to

```
Java_Home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_76
```

and save it.

It works for me in case of `openMQ`

I hope it will work for you.